# composer require laravel/breeze --dev has an issue with php version

Tags: php, laravel, breeze

I launch the command in terminal from my laravel project:
`composer require laravel/breeze --dev`

But this is my error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                 
  Package laravel/breeze has a PHP requirement incompatible with your PHP version, PHP extensions and Composer version
```

If I type `php -v` :

```
PHP 7.1.33 (cli) (built: Jan 18 2020 13:49:07) ( NTS )
```

Then with `brew upgrade php`I have error `Error: php not installed`.
So I do `brew install php` .
Response is:

```
Warning: You are using macOS 10.13.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Twitter or any other official channels. You are responsible for resolving
any issues you experience while you are running this
old version.

Error: php: no bottle available!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install php7.3 via brew. your current version is probably installed by macOS.

```
brew install php@7.3
```

Dont forget to export the new path

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin:$PATH"'
```

Comment: I get the same error:  php@7.4: no bottle available!